# apache/mysql slow response but cpu/memory and limits not reached

Tags: mysql, performance, apache, ubuntu

I have a very strange problem.

I'm running a very busy LAMP web service on Ubuntu (over a million visitors daily) and lately I'm having problems with apache responding slowly.

The odd thing is that neither the webserver machine nor the database machine are reaching any sort of limits. CPU usage and memory all look okay (they're basically not even doing 10% of their max). Apache has enough idle processes to handle incoming requests. Currently it's sitting around 350 to 500 requests per second and it's configured for 800.

I've played around with the Mysql settings (innodb) without any success. I checked the slow query log, process list, etc. and there's no sign of any slow queries or anything holding back the system.

The only thing at the moment I can do to keep the system up to speed is disabling some database calls on a users visit. In other words limit the amount of database calls being made on each user visit. But the fact I have to do this just stuns me as the machines are nowhere near their limits.

I checked disk usage with iotop and it's not much either. Both servers are double AMD 16 core machines with Vertex 4 SSD's and 16GB RAM.

I'm starting to be a bit lost so I'm wondering: do you guys have any suggestions on what else I can try or look for?

Small update:
If I run the following query it comes up with 21343. Which could mean my innodb_buffer_pool_size of 12G is too low? Is it possible I'm having problems with this?

```
SELECT CEILING(Total_InnoDB_Bytes/POWER(1024,2)) RIBPS FROM
(SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length) Total_InnoDB_Bytes
FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB') A;
```

Here are my config setup,top and iftop for both machines.

```
Apache:
Timeout 30
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
KeepAliveTimeout 2
StartServers 100
MinSpareServers 100
MaxSpareServers 200
MaxClients          1000
MaxRequestsPerChild 0



Mysql:
default-character-set = utf8
skip-external-locking
skip-name-resolve
skip-locking
open_files_limit = 102400
wait_timeout = 30
interactive_timeout = 30
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 256K
thread_cache_size       = 50
max_connections        = 50000
table_cache            = 4096
thread_concurrency     = 8
innodb_thread_concurrency = 8
innodb_buffer_pool_size=12G
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=10M
innodb_log_file_size=1500M
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
tmp_table_size         = 128M
max_heap_table_size    = 128M
query_cache_limit       = 5M
query_cache_size        = 128M
log_slow_queries        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 3

Top output apacheserver:
Tasks: 842 total,   1 running, 841 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  3.0%us,  0.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 96.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  16446884k total, 11921852k used,  4525032k free,   183140k buffers
Swap:  9541624k total,    58596k used,  9483028k free,  7439992k cached

Top output mysql server:
Tasks: 197 total,   1 running, 196 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.2%us,  0.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.5%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  16446544k total, 16197496k used,   249048k free,   147632k buffers
Swap: 16755756k total,   277020k used, 16478736k free,  1976760k cached

iftop apache server:
TX:             cumm:  5.68MB   peak:   4.84Mb  rates:   4.56Mb  3.11Mb  3.25Mb
RX:                     973KB            647Kb            643Kb   556Kb   556Kb
TOTAL:                 6.63MB           5.48Mb           5.19Mb  3.65Mb  3.79Mb

iftop mysql server
TX:             cumm:   954B    peak:   1.36Kb  rates:      0b    541b    347b
RX:                    4.59KB           4.69Kb           4.69Kb  2.89Kb  1.67Kb
TOTAL:                 5.52KB           4.69Kb           4.69Kb  3.41Kb  2.01Kb
```

Comment: On such a busy website, the first thing that comes to mind is to set up a light webserver (like nginx) to serve static content. Also, apache2 supports response time in the access log (i think it's `%T` in `LogFormat`) so you can pinpoint what's taking the longest. KeepAlive should always be set to a possible lowest. To be more helpful, we'd really need more info like conf files and some (sample) access/error logs

Comment: I got %T setup in the logformat thats how i'm seeing its slow in response.. We have all static content serving from a seperate nginx server already.. I've edited the top part to show my config settings.

Comment: Run a load average, using the "top" command, and post the 3 numbers.  Also, have you looked at network bandwidth?  Maybe you're just maxing out your pipe?

Comment: Added top and iftop outputs from both servers. Thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: Maybe good to note that everything is connected with an gigabit switch. So as it seems it cannot really be a bandwidth issue?

Comment: The load average is not visible. If you are IO bound (or have DB locks) the load average will probably show it. On ubuntu you can see load average with `w` or `cat /proc/loadavg`. Also, your config looks good. Only thing is the `long_query_time = 3` is too high to detect an issue. Try setting it to 0.5 or lower and check the slow_query log again.

Comment: Output of loadaverage 0.01 0.03 0.06 1/574 14209 Not sure what it means? I've setted now the slow query to 0.5. Thanks

Comment: Disable slow queries log will improve performance

Answer (score 2):

I found out the slow down was caused by iptables reaching its connection limit.
I looked in the system log files where I noticed the following error: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.

Raising the nf_conntrack value in the sysctl.conf file resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

With the latest info and comments added, it all starts to make sense.

Your insert statements lock the tables, causing a bottleneck, probably because of an index in your userlog table.

So the (assumed) flow is

- user requests the page
- insert into userlog table needs x milliseconds, for that duration of x milliseconds the table (or index or autoincrement column) is locked, not allowing other insert statements on the same table
- next user comes before the previous insert has finished, so will have to wait before inserting to userlog table. with so many user, the queue grows rapidly giving very slow response times even though the server is just sitting.

**Solutions(?):**

This is a major issue with most database systems. I've had a similar issue sometime ago and solved it by creating a table with a single column (no index of course) in which I inserted the sql statement that I wanted to run. Then run a cronjob (every 5 minutes) which connects to Database and performs all the statements in a single transaction. My traffic was much lower and hardware by far inferior so you may need some finetuning with the above solution.

Other things you could try involve:

- removing all indexes and autoincrements of your userlog table
- create a secondary table with the same values but no id, then insert to the real userlog table and remove from secondary table. (similar to the first)
- use a fast storage like memcached or redis for userlog, and run a daemon or cron to export statistics
- use asynchronous db insert, e.g. with a daemon that listens to a socket and inserts the data to userlog table. Then your script contacts the daemon with the data to insert, the daemon responds instantly, but append the insert command in a FIFO queue and insert when possible.

PS. Insert and update statements always need special care when happening inside high traffic webpages. Select statements are much easier and you shouldn't worry about them as long as you have proper indexes

Comment: You might be on to something here. The visitlog table was already actually a temp table from which I have a cronjob to process these entry's. But I did indeed have a auto increment index on this table. I have removed this index now I've turned on the insert query again i'll monitor it for a while..

Comment: Unfortunately your suggestion did not help. The problem actually had to do with nf_conntrack maxing out. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

> slow response

Where are the numbers?

> Currently it's sitting around 350 to 500 requests per second and it's configured for 800

How exactly do you configure requests per second in Apache?

> there's no sign of any slow queries....long_query_time = 3

But it seems that each request is resulting in multiple database calls - hence there could be multiples of up to 3 seconds for each request you're not seeing. Really you should be logging performance stats for all queries (a spinning rust device might be more appropriate for this)

Based on the numbers you've provided the performance is unlikely to be due to i/o (0 wait). It does take a long time to work through 12Gb of data (latency on DDR3 alone is around 0.5s, while optimally, bandwidth reduces this to around 5s) but your sys and usr times are low too implying this is not the problem.

So the most logical place to start looking for problems is in the network latency between the webservers and database.

Are you using trivial ORM? Switching to factories (or at least lazy loading) might give a big improvement.

Check for packet loss and collisions, make sure your NICs are are configured correctly (speed, duplex), delayed interrupts enabled on the NIC drivers.

Also make sure there aren't issue with scheduling on the web server (e.g. evertything pinned on the same core).

Comment: Well basically as long as I don't do any inserts or updates for every visit all is fine. So now every visit just generates 2 or 3 read query's. But once I turn on an insert query which I want to use to log every visit into a table all goes nuts and my apache log fills up with slow requests ranging from 3 to 31 seconds timeout. I checked already all NIC stats and theres no errors at all. All those counters are 0. Techniques like lazy loading should not be necessary if I'm not even near any of my machines capacity right? Or are there any other limits involved which i'm not aware of?

Comment: I just did a file transfer test between the 2 machines. And i'm reaching about 50MB/s So not a full Gbit but seems fast enough?